# ios-provisioning-portal for PushSharp

Tags: iphone, pushsharp

I want to develop demo application at my development machine.
Here I want to use pushsharp for mobile Notifications and further I want to use it on
iphone.

For pushsharp integration with iphone I requires ios provisioning
reference: https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/wiki/How-to-Configure-&-Send-Apple-Push-Notifications-using-PushSharp

But https://developer.apple.com is asking for $99 dollars for it use.

So here my question is that Is there any free/developer key is available to this or I need to purchase this.

I need to show some demo before going to purchase any thing.

please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommended that developer use the code singing when they want to test application on device. So for that purpose developer have to purchase such a/c. for create provisioning profile and certificates.

you can found more information at developer portal regarding setup profile check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles/CreatingandDownloadingDevelopmentProvisioningProfiles.html). Also for APNS have to set that enabled in your app id.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your app in Simulator without purchase of $99.

But if you want to test your app in physical device then you must have to purchase developer account of $99.
Also if you want to test APNS then also you need this purchasable account.

So, I recommended to purchase it for other benefits as well.